# set the frame size when orientation is changed in ios

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to change the orientation of a view in ios 6. When the orientation is changed, I want to set the frame size of the views.

My Sample Code for orientation change:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSInteger mask = 0;

    intOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if(intOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || intOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else 
        if(intOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
            mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
        }
    }
    NSLog (@"mask %d",mask);
    return mask;
}

// Here now mask value is 2 because my default mode is portrait.
```

Now when I change my orientation to landscape, I want to set the frame size. Please guide me on how to do that.

ok..Can I set the frame size for the view like dis by taking the version and comparing it in viewdidLoad:

```
orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

NSString *reqSysVer = @"6.0";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
NSLog (@"ios version %@",currSysVer);
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
{
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 800);


        self.tableView1.frame = CGRectMake(1, 0, 764,510);

    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft)
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1300, 370);
        self.tableView1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1300, 370);
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    }

}
```

Comment: this seems like something Auto Layout should be handling...

Comment: I dont want to use the autoLayout option because my code should work with the previous ios versions too @MichaelDautermann

Comment: ahhh, then you probably should have not used the magic word "ios6" in your title (and I will edit your question to remove "ios6").  iOS 6 is where Auto Layout came into play as an option, whereas you want to support iOS 5 and potentially even older OS'es.

Comment: ok.. pls have a look at my edited question can i do lyk dat

Answer (score 2):

you can get a notification when the interface orientation changes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and add a function like:

```
- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {   
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientation...)
    {
        // add some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use Auto Layout or Constraints, I think.
But you can also check for the device orientation using

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```

or check the size (e.g. for iPhone 5 support) using

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

// Update:
Consider that on iOS 8 width and height were switched in landscape. So witdh and height are always depending on the orientation now.